# How to open few different activites on recyclerview different item click using if or case method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am currently using recycler view in a fragment. I have 4 items in my recycler view list. Now I want to open 4 new different activities using the if/case method. But I can open one activity and not able to open other activities as per their positions. Here is my RecyclerViewAdapter java code. 
Also please let me know the best practice to open on click listener.

```
    package com.kidslearning.course.adapter;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.Image;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import com.kidslearning.course.NewHindiActivity;
    import com.kidslearning.course.R;
    import com.kidslearning.course.fragment.EnglishFragment;
    import com.kidslearning.course.fragment.HindiFragment;
    import com.kidslearning.course.fragment.MathFragment;
    import com.kidslearning.course.model.HindiFragmentModel;

    import java.util.List;

    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

        Context mContext;
        List<HindiFragmentModel> mData;
        private MathFragment MathFragment;

        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<HindiFragmentModel> mData) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mData = mData;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v;
            v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.fragmentdesign,parent,false);
            MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);
            mContext = v.getContext();

            return vHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
            holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewHindiActivity.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

       //now I want to open other activity by clicking on 2nd recycler view item.    

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView tv_name;
            private ImageView img;
            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
                img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your `onClick()` code

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FirstActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                } else if (position == 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FourthActivity.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `onClick` item

```
Intent intent;
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), NewHindiActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will want to not use if/case stategment you can also add to model destination page, for example:

```
class HindiFragmentModel {
...
private Activity pageToGo;
...
public Activity getPageToGo() {
    return pageToGo; }

public void setPageToGo(Activity pageToGo) {
    this.pageToGo = pageToGo; }
}
```

Setter uses:

```
yourHindiFragmentModelObject.setPageToGo(new DestinationActivity())
```

And finally in adapter :

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), mData.get(position).getPageToGo().getClass());
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I open other activites using following...or it will open only one activity----- Setter uses:
yourHindiFragmentModelObject.setPageToGo(new DestinationActivity1())
yourHindiFragmentModelObject.setPageToGo(new DestinationActivity2())
yourHindiFragmentModelObject.setPageToGo(new DestinationActivity3())
yourHindiFragmentModelObject.setPageToGo(new DestinationActivity4())

Comment: In place where you're creating your data list you need to set destinantion activity for correct object . For example for first item it will be e.g "new NewHindiActivity()"